# Setting window background color with XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a standard XAML styled window in WPF (< Window ....)

In this window I insert a resource dictionary

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/Global.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

In the Global.xaml dicionary I have the following code:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <Style TargetType="Window">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>            
   </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Nothing out of ordinary anywhere.  Except it doesn't work, when I compile and run the app, the window background is shown in default white. BUT in the designer tab in  Visual Studio where you can see the preview of your window, the background color is correctly changed to red. I don't understand.
I don't have any other styles inserted anywhere that could be overwriting the window's background color.
So how is it possible that in the preview tab it works correctly, but when i actually run the app, it doesn't? What am I doing wrong here?

---

Here is the entire window code:

```
<Window x:Class="Apptest.EditBook"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="EditBook" Height="300" Width="300">
 <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/Global.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/Controls.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>

   </Grid>
 </Window>
```

Comment: Please post the XAML for the window.

Comment: Okay, I posted the entire code, but it's an empty test window with no content so there is nothing that could be breaking anything I think

Comment: And just to be complete... whats in the controls dictionary?

Comment: Just some style for buttons. But that isn't causing it, as I tried to remove the link for it completely and it still didn't worked.

Comment: Just to check.. is your app.xaml StartUpUri property still set to MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: It may help: Clean the project -by visual studio-, open `bin` directory and delete everything in; recompile and run. Sometimes we need this

Comment: Im getting the same thing when re-creating your project.. give me a few moments.

Comment: BenjaminPaul: Yes it is.   Javad_Amiry: Just tried it, but no dice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK... So this is because your window is actually a type deriving from Window...

```
public partial class EditBook : Window { }
```

Target type does not yet work with derived types so you will need to add a key to the style and add it to each window you create that you want to use the style for..

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="MyWindowStyle">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>            
   </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

then you will need to apply the style in the window...

```
<Window x:Class="Apptest.EditBook"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="EditBook" Height="300" Width="300" Style="{StaticResource MyWindowStyle}">
 <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/Global.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/Controls.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>

   </Grid>
 </Window>
```

Hope this helps... there is no better solution from what I can see.

Comment: I see. Well, that is a bummer, but I can live with it. But how is it possible that in the preview tab in visual studio it actually works?

Comment: Good question.. although to be honest... I have no idea.